# Automatically reconfigure router when it is reset

Tags: access-control, router

Is it possible to automatically reconfigure a router when the router is reset?

My 13-year old son is resetting the router to bypass time controls (set to go off at midnight).  I can configure the router to block access midnight to 5am when he should be asleep, but resetting the router bypasses this. The router can save a backup file (config.bin) and restore settings from the file, but this requires 
1) being awake, 
2) being aware in real time of when the router is reset
3) logging into the router and 
4) restoring the settings.

Is there a way I can reasonably have a connected device (ideally my android phone or something in the router itself) log into the router and restore the settings when the router is reset?  My computer isn't generally on full time.

The router is a tplink router that has a web-based settings panel.
I'm technically literate, but by no means an expert.

To address the comments that are likely to arise about this being a parenting/ communication problem, I fully admit and accept this criticism, but he is 13 and constantly staying up until 2-4am is causing problems and he isn't responding to discussions and other consequences. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If taking your son's computer away is not a workable consequence, then I would suggest you go old-school:

**Glue a piece of metal over the reset button.**